# JavaScript - add character in string whenever another character is found

Tags: javascript

I have a string that looks like this :

```
LE PUY EN VELAY (NIVEAU_SITE)LYON 03 (@A)01AIGLETTE (GEX)
```

What I need is to modify this string so that each time it finds the character  **`)`** it adds a **`,`** just after.

It would look like this :

```
LE PUY EN VELAY (NIVEAU_SITE), LYON 03 (@A), 01AIGLETTE (GEX)
```

**The last ")" doest not have to have a "," sign after**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `replace()` and regex `/\)(?=.*\))/g`

**Where**

`\)` matches the character `)` literally

Positive Lookahead `(?=.*\))`

`.*` matches any character (except for line terminators)

```js
var str = "LE PUY EN VELAY (NIVEAU_SITE)LYON 03 (@A)01AIGLETTE (GEX)";
str = str.replace(/\)(?=.*\))/g,"), ");
console.log(str);
```

Comment: @Mamum OP updated the question, you might want to update your answer as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `split` `join` and `splice`

```js
var a = "LE PUY EN VELAY (NIVEAU_SITE)LYON 03 (@A)01AIGLETTE (GEX)";
var x = a.split('');

x.forEach(function(e, j) {
  if (e == ')')
    x.splice(j + 1, 1, ',')
})

x[x.length - 1] = '';
console.log(x.join(''))
```

Answer (score 1):

While Mamum answer is most optimised and clean but if you don't know regular expression, you can do something like this

You can try something like this..

1. Split and make it into array
2. Map the array and make changes accordingly (using if-else condition)
3. Join the Array

```js
 let str = "LE PUY EN VELAY (NIVEAU_SITE)LYON 03 (@A)01AIGLETTE (GEX)";

str = str.split('').map((el, index) => {
  if (str.length === index + 1) return el
  if (el === ')')  return '),'
  else return el
})
console.log(str.join(''));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const updateString = (str)=>{

    str = str.replace(/["')]/g,"),");
    if(str.charAt(str.length -2) == ')' && str.charAt(str.length -1) == ',' ){

                str = str.slice(0, str.length-1);
          }

}
```